# Add 2 tensors with different rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, addition

I have 2 tensors: A with shape of `(None, 16, 7, 7, 1024)` and B with shape of `(1, 16, 7, 7, 1024)`. I add these tensors using `keras.layers.add([A, B])`. I expect to have a tensor with shape of (**None**, 16, 7, 7, 1024) but I got (**1**, 16, 7, 7, 1024) ==> notice that batch size now becomes 1.
How to get the result as I want (`None`)?

Code:

```
_h_state = np.zeros((16, 7, 7, 1024))
h_state = Input(tensor=tf.constant(_h_state, dtype=tf.float32), name='input_h_state')
enc = encoder.output

enc_x = Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), name='enc_conv')(enc)
h_state_expanded = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, 0))(h_state)
h_state_x = Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), name='h_state_conv')(h_state_expanded)
x = layers.add([enc_x, h_state_x])
x = Activation('tanh')(x)
.
.
.
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: This should just be working fine. Are you sure your original batch size is greater than 1?

Comment: the original input for B is (16, 7, 7, 1024) and I add extra dimension so that I can perform Conv3D on it. After that I want to perform addition with A. I want to keep first dimension of the result to be None

Comment: Another information, original input for B is constant value without batch size

Comment: @donto Could you please share reproducible code?

Comment: @rvinas Question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print `x.shape`, the output is `(None, 16, 7, 7, 1024)`, but interestingly both `plot_model` and `model.summary` show the "unbroadcast" first dimension.

I believe you are right - the method [`keras.layers._Merge.compute_output_shape`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L163) might not be handling broadcasting correctly for the first dimension in this particular case. That is something that should probably be fixed via a pull request.

In the meantime, you can instead use:

```
x = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])([enc_x, h_state_x])
```

which gives the expected output shape.

Comment: Yeah, when I print `x.shape`, first dimension is `None`, but `plot_model()` tells different. For your information, I'm using Windows 10, tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0, Keras 2.2.4. Also, your solution works flawlessly! Thanks.